# Redirect 301 if QUERY_STRING is different than set

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do 301 redirects using .htaccess

I have an addresses which looks like that:

```
/index.php?option=calendario&task=view_calendar&month=12&year=2017&Itemid=100
/index.php?option=calendario&task=view_calendar&month=12&year=2017&Itemid=101
```

and I want to redirect to

```
/index.php?option=calendario&task=view_calendar&month=12&year=2017&Itemid=400
```

always when the `Itemid` is different than `400`
of course, month and year can change

I'm wrote this redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php?option=calendario&task=view_calendar&(month=.+)&(year=.+)&(Itemid=.+)$    /index.php?option=calendario&task=view_calendar&month=$1&year=$2&Itemid=490
```

However, it doesn't work, I'm not if I need to use mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not part of URL string that RewriteMatch is compared to. You can use `RewriteCond` check against the `%{QUERY_STRING}`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !option=calendario&task=view_calendar&month=([^&]+)&year=([^&]+)&Itemid=400
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php?option=calendario&task=view_calendar&month=%1&year=%2&Itemid=400 [R=301,L]
```